# Sequence of running code when using Cypress.Promise in Cypress

Tags: javascript, promise, cypress

Here is the code for the online tutorial to get title of elements:

**test.js**

```
it('',function(){
        cy.visit("https://www.simplyrecipes.com/")
        new SRHomePage().getHeroComponentTitle2().then(title => {
           cy.log(title);
        });
    });
```

**SRHomePage.js**

```
export class SRHomePage{
    getHeroComponentTitle2(){
        let title = '';
         cy.get('.showcase__hero .card__title').then($title => {
            title  = $title.text().trim()
        });

        return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
            cy.wrap('').then(() => resolve(title))})
    }
}
```

IN SRHomePage.js, when I use

```
return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {
                cy.wrap('').then(() => resolve(title))})
        }
```

=> get title

Order is:

```
1 visithttps://www.simplyrecipes.com/
2 get.showcase__hero .card__title
3 wrap
4 log Gruyère Mushroom Pizza With Balsamic Glaze
```

If I use

```
return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => resolve(title))
```

=> Do not get title

Order is

```
1 visithttps://www.simplyrecipes.com/
2 log
3 get.showcase__hero .card__title
```

I really confused the way work for Promise, cy.wrap('') and asynchronous handling in Cypress in this sittuation

Please explain to me, I really know to understand, thank a lot

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: The problem is not in the line where you `return new Cypress.Promise` but rather when you try to assign the `title` variable from within the first `.then()` callback. Don't do that. Just return the promise created by `.then()`: `return cy.get('.showcase__hero .card__title').then($title => { return $title.text().trim() });`!

Comment: The difference between your two `return new Cypress.Promise()` lines in the one with `cy.wrap()` does not take the value from closure `title` ***until the Cypress queue has run***. Many people (with no understanding of Cypress) assume that the commands are returning promises, when in fact they are running a queue of commands, and the queue is started ***after*** the test code has run through.